# Looping with dplyr function?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a large dataset and want to look at the relationship between various libraries (owners) and materials owned (objects). So far I've been doing this manually, by spreading and gathering to count the overlap between each owner.

Is there a way to loop this type of function so that I don't have to repeat it n number of times?

Here's a sample of data (already spread) and the work do gather it back.

```
library(dplyr)

object <- c(1:10)
A <- sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE)
B <- sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE)
C <- sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE)
D <- sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(object, A, B, C, D)

dfA <- df %>% filter(A == 1)
dfA$owner1 <- "A"
dfA <- dfA %>% gather(owner2, overlap, A:D, factor_key = TRUE)
dfA <- dfA %>% filter(overlap != 0)

dfB <- df %>% filter(B == 1)
dfB$owner1 <- "B"
dfB <- dfB %>% gather(owner2, overlap, A:D, factor_key = TRUE)
dfB <- dfB %>% filter(overlap != 0)

dfC <- df %>% filter(C == 1)
dfC$owner1 <- "C"
dfC <- dfC %>% gather(owner2, overlap, A:D, factor_key = TRUE)
dfC <- dfC %>% filter(overlap != 0)

dfD <- df %>% filter(D == 1)
dfD$owner1 <- "D"
dfD <- dfD %>% gather(owner2, overlap, A:D, factor_key = TRUE)
dfD <- dfD %>% filter(overlap != 0)

df2 <- rbind(dfA, dfB) %>% rbind(dfC) %>% rbind(dfD)
```

The result allows you to count how many objects each owner has (when it's owner1 and owner2), as well as the overlap between owners.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following using tidyverse. It's a bit dense, so I added comments:

```
pmap(df, \(...) {                           # iterate through rows
  c(...)[-1] %>%                            # drop first column
    .[. == 1] %>%                           # columns with value 1
    names() %>%                             # owners (A, B, ..)
    (\(xs) expand.grid(xs, xs)) %>%         # generate pairs of owners
    mutate(object = c(...)[1], .before = 1) # add object column
}) %>%
  bind_rows()                               # combine
```

Returning (abbreviated):

```
  object Var1 Var2
1      1    A    A
2      1    C    A
3      1    A    C
4      1    C    C
5      2    A    A
6      2    B    A
...
```

For R < 4.1

```
pmap(df, function(...) {
  c(...)[-1] %>%
    .[. == 1] %>%
    names() %>%
    (function(xs) expand.grid(xs, xs)) %>%
    mutate(object = c(...)[1], .before = 1)
}) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

Comment: So far, these are the errors I get when running that: 
`> pmap(df, \(...) {
Error: unexpected input in "pmap(df, \"
>   c(...)[-1] %>% 
+     .[. == 1] %>% 
+     names() %>% 
+     (\(xs) expand.grid(xs, xs)) %>% 
Error: unexpected input in:
"    names() %>% 
    (\"
>     mutate(object = c(...)[1], .before = 1) 
Error in mutate(object = c(...)[1], .before = 1) : 
  '...' used in an incorrect context
> }) %>% 
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
>   bind_rows()
# A tibble: 0 x 0
>`

Comment: Either change the first line to `pmap(df, function(...) { ` or upgrade to the newest version of R (4.1) :)

Comment: Updated with a version for R < 4.1.

Comment: Upgraded, yet the < 4.1 code is the one that worked. Oh well, thanks!